# Jquery Point A to Point B - Restart

Tags: jquery

I have an image that I am animating from left to right. I want it to start back at the left and repeat. Right now, it does that, but it's visible when it returns from the right to left.

right now: left to right, to left
what I want: left to right. left to right.

Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

If it is visible, you can use `hide()` to hide the image while is going back to the left

Answer (score 0):

How about calling a animation loop like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/yazze/1/

It resets the css to left 0 every time so there's no animation from right to left.

```
function left_to_right(target){
    target.css('left','0');
    target.animate(
        {"left":"90%"}
        , 1000, function() {
            left_to_right(target);
        }
    );
}
```